# How do I create graphs like this in python?

Tags: python, chess, python-chess

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVO3o.png)

I would like to generate graphs in this format, does anyone have code to be able to generate

Comment: We don't work on such broad questions here on stackoverflow. There are several high quality plotting packages written for python. But you'll have to research which one you might want to use.

Answer (score 2):

you can use de matplotlib library, i think you can use the Horizontal stacked bar plot.
Here is an example of how you can use it:

```
 import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "height_2019":[40, 12, 10, 26, 36,39],
    "height_2020":[19, 8, 30, 21, 38,29],
    "height_2021":[10, 10, 42, 17, 37,23]
    }, index=['John','Jack','Sam','Shane','Smith','Bill'])

df.plot(kind='barh',figsize=(8,8),stacked=True)
plt.show()
```